# boot asus zenbook ux433f from USB?

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, asus-laptop

I would like to run Linux from a USB drive, on my asus zenbook ux433f but I simply cannot locate the option/trigger to launch my USB drive - how to?

Is there a special version of Linux I can use or some moethhod that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make your Linux boot drive using the guide on this website:
[How to Create a Bootable Linux USB Flash Drive, the Easy Way](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/)

Then follow these steps to boot your Zenbook with the USB drive.

1. Shutdown the Zenbook
2. Insert your USB drive
3. Power on the Zenbook
4. Press the ESC key repeatedly while booting up
5. You should see a boot menu with your USB drive listed as a boot option.